# how to load an android project

Tags: android

I'm new to android development and learning it through google's training document.
I've downloaded a demo but don't know how to load it to my Eclipse with ADT plug in.

The following figure is the directories of the demo.
[image]

Comment: "File, Import, Import existing project" should do the trick :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the eclipse project list then import project. 
Choose Android project and select the demo s repository.

Answer (score 1):

1.File->Import->General->Existing Projects into Workspace, Next

2 Select root directory: /path/to/project

3 Projects->Select All

4 UNCHECK both "Copy projects into workspace" and "Add project to working sets"

5.Finish

or you can use this tutorial http://android.programmerguru.com/how-to-import-android-project-in-eclipse/